# How to analyze Go (golang) crash logs

Tags: go, tcp, irc

So my application crashed and I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is only from the error messages. Because it ran for hours fine.

this is the error

```
(err): net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc20802ac30, 0x0, 0x0)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x42
(err): net.(*netFD).Read(0xc20802abd0, 0xc208083000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x7fab4f8082b8, 0xb)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x34c
(err): net.(*conn).Read(0xc208038090, 0xc208083000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/net.go:122 +0xe7
(err): bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc208004540)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1b3
(err): bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0xc208004540, 0x7ffff8000000000a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:298 +0x22c
(err): bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine(0xc208004540, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:326 +0x69
(err): net/textproto.(*Reader).readLineSlice(0xc208022d50, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/textproto/reader.go:55 +0x9d
(err): net/textproto.(*Reader).ReadLine(0xc208022d50, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
(err):     /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/textproto/reader.go:36 +0x4e
(err): main.(*Bot).ListenToConnection(0xc208046460, 0x7fab4f809518, 0xc208038090)
(err):     /home/gempir/gempbroker/main.go:73 +0xab
(err): created by main.(*Bot).CreateConnection
(err):     /home/gempir/gempbroker/main.go:106 +0x8a3
```

I found that main.go:73 which is a simple Readline reading from a TCP connection

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    tp := textproto.NewReader(reader)
    for {
        line, err := tp.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            break // break loop on errors
        }
        // do stuff
    }
```

main.go:106 just creates a goroutine for listening to the connection

```
go listenToConnection(conn)
```

How do I find out what the error logs actually mean and find a solution to my problem?

Comment: What is the error that you discard here? `line, err := tp.ReadLine(); if err != nil { break };`

Comment: oh well that was stupid of me to not log. thanks.